# How to Translate text without losing newline characters?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm using Firebase ML Kit Translate to translate some text from Japanese to English.

I'm just using the example code they have in their documentation:

```
func translate (input: String) {

      print(input)
      translator.translate(input) { translatedText, error in
      guard error == nil, let translatedText = translatedText else { return }

      self.output = translatedText
      print(self.output)

      return
    }
```

When I input Japanese text, I notice all the newline characters are ignored and the English translation is in one block of text. Is there a setting to enable newlines or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This is known behavior of the underlying translation engine, which strips out any non-linguistic content.

In general, it's difficult to impossible to accurately preserve non-linguistic content in translation, as the grammatical structure of the translated sentence might be entirely different, so there is no natural place for the separators to go. For example, if I were to translate the sentence "I saw \n the dog" (with a newline in the middle) into German, the German version of the pure sentence is "Ich habe den Hund gesehen", with the predicate at the end of the sentence and the object in the middle. Should the newline go after the predicate ("Ich habe den Hund gesehen \n") or before the object ("Ich habe \n den Hund gesehen")?

---

If the text is broken into paragraphs (or other blocks) along sentences, you could translate each of them separately, and then join them again:

```java
List<Task<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (String paragraph : text.split("\n\n")) {
    tasks.add(translator.translate(paragraph));
}
Task<String> resultTask = Tasks.whenAll(tasks).onSuccessTask(aVoid -> {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Task<String> task : tasks) {
        results.add(task.getResult);
    }
    return Tasks.forResult(String.join("\n\n", results));
});
```

or in Swift:

```swift
let paragraphs = text.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
var results = [String]()
for paragraph in paragraphs {
  translator.translate(paragraph) { result, error in
    guard let unwrappedResult = result else {
      // Handle error
      return
    }
    results.append(unwrappedResult)
    if (results.count == paragraphs.count) {
      let result = results.joined(separator: "\n\n")
      // Handle result
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My preference is to preserve paragraphing (which is what Google Translate online does).

Comment: (Looks like I can't add formatted text in a comment. I'll update the answer instead.)

Comment: Please avoid words such as impossible because as I tested the HMS ML Kit translator, the engine managed to preserve the non-linguistic part. The original string formatted with "\n" was kept after the translation. IMHO the ML Kit Translation is just a light weight half cook version from original Google Translate thus developer should provide a fix for this issue.